# MYSQL Join tables with no unique id on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

Table Main:

```
TestNumber    PassageNumber    QuestionNumber
1             1                1
1             1                2
1             1                3
1             2                1
1             2                2
1             2                3
```

Table Child:

```
TestNumber    PassageNumber    QuestionNumber    User    SelectedAnswer
1             1                1                 X       A
1             2                2                 X       B
```

I want to show the data in main table that is not in child table based on a test number and user. So the results i am looking for are the following where the rows from main table are the ones NOT in child:

```
TestNumber    PassageNumber    QuestionNumber
1             1                2
1             1                3
1             2                1
1             2                3
```

I have tried the following query and variations with no luck:

```
SELECT a.passagenumber, a.questionnumber FROM Main a left outer join 
Child b on a.testnumber=b.testnumber where b.user = 'X' 
and b.testnumber=1 and a.testnumber=1 and b.selectedanswer is not null
```

I understand if i had a unique id this would be easy to solve but in this case that is not an option. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thin you can use not in

```
SELECT a.passagenumber, a.questionnumber FROM Main a 
where ( a.testnumber, a.passagenumber, a.questionumber) 
         not in ( select b.testnumber, b.passagenumber, b.questionumber 
                    from  Child b where b.user = 'X' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you join the tables on the three fields, using left join and where the child table value is null?

```
SELECT  p.TestNumber
       ,p.PassageNumber
       ,p.QuestionNumber
FROM    Parent p
        LEFT JOIN Child c ON c.TestNumber = p.TestNumber
                              AND c.PassageNumber = p.PassageNumber
                              AND c.QuestionNumber = p.QuestionNumber
                              AND c.[User] = 'X'
WHERE   c.TestNumber IS NULL;
```